# Redux State shows data, but React Props returns null

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a Redux-React web app that allows the asynchronous of data throughout the app. I am running into an issue where my Redux State shows data:

[Shows Redux DevTools and current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRGQS.png)

However, when I go to call the prop for my app, it comes back as null. No matter what I've tried to connect the two, nothing is working.

Web App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Buscard from './components/Buscard';
import DispatchHeader from './components/DispatchHeader';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import './style.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import addVan from './store/actions/add_Vans';
// import getVansList, { reorderVans } from './store/actions/get_van_list';
// import getRiderList from './store/actions/get_rider_list';
import RiderItem from './components/riderItem';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { root } from 'postcss';
import withReducer from 'app/store/withReducer';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import reducer from './store/reducers';
import * as Actions from './store/actions';

const buttonStyle = {
    margin: '0 10px'
}


class AdminApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            openModal: false,
            P_Key: '',
            vanName: '',
            seatsTotal: '',
            newpartyNM: '',
            newaddress1: '',
            newnumParty: '',
            newnumCooler: '',
            newphoneNum: '',
            newpickUp: '',
            columns: {
                'column-1': {
                    id: 'column-1',
                    vans: this.props.vansList
                }
            },
            columns2: {
                'column-2': {
                    id: 'column-2',
                    vans: this.props.vansList
                }
            }
        }

        this.handleNameVanChange = this.handleNameVanChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTotalSeatsChage = this.handleTotalSeatsChage.bind(this);
        this.toggleModalState = this.toggleModalState.bind(this);
        this.clearVanFormCloseModal = this.clearVanFormCloseModal.bind(this);
        this.handleVanCreation = this.handleVanCreation.bind(this);
        this.handleRiderEdit = this.handleRiderEdit.bind(this);
        this.handlePartyEditChange = this.handlePartyEditChange.bind(this);
        this.handleAddressEditChange = this.handleAddressEditChange.bind(this);
        this.handleNumPartyEditChange = this.handleNumPartyEditChange.bind(this);
        this.handleNumCoolerEditChange = this.handleNumCoolerEditChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePhoneNumEditChange = this.handlePhoneNumEditChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePickUpEditChange = this.handlePickUpEditChange.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getRiderList();
    }

    renderRiders() {
        //console.log(this.props.riderList)
        return this.props.riderList.map((rider, index) => {
            return (
                <RiderItem key={rider.P_Key}
                    riderList={rider}
                    editRider={this.handleRiderEdit}
                    //onVanChange={this.handleNameVanChange}
                    handlePartyEditChange={this.handlePartyEditChange}
                    handleAddressEditChange={this.handleAddressEditChange}
                    handleNumPartyEditChange={this.handleNumPartyEditChange}
                    handleNumCoolerEditChange={this.handleNumCoolerEditChange}
                    handlePhoneNumEditChange={this.handlePhoneNumEditChange}
                    handlePickUpEditChange={this.handlePickUpEditChange}
                    newpartyNM={this.state.newpartyNM}
                    newaddress1={this.state.newaddress1}
                    newnumParty={this.state.newnumParty}
                    newnumCooler={this.state.newnumCooler}
                    newphoneNum={this.state.newphoneNum}
                    newpickUp={this.state.newpickUp}
                    index={index}
                />)
        })
    }

    toggleModalState() {
        if (this.state.openModal) {
            this.clearVanFormCloseModal();
        } else {
            this.setState({
                openModal: true
            })
        }
    }

    handleNameVanChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            vanName: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleTotalSeatsChage(e) {
        this.setState({
            seatsTotal: e.target.value
        });
    }

    clearVanFormCloseModal() {
        this.setState({
            vanName: '',
            seatsTotal: '',
            openModal: false
        })
    }
    handlePartyEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newpartyNM: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleAddressEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newaddress1: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleNumPartyEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newnumParty: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleNumCoolerEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newnumCooler: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handlePhoneNumEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newphoneNum: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handlePickUpEditChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            newpickUp: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleVanCreation() {
        //e.preventDefaults();
        const vans = {
            nameVan: this.state.vanName,
            totalSeats: this.state.seatsTotal
        }
        this.props.addVan(vans);
        this.clearVanFormCloseModal();
    }

    handleRiderEdit() {
        const riders = {
            partyNM: this.state.newpartyNM,
            address1: this.state.newaddress1,
            numParty: this.state.newnumParty,
            numCooler: this.state.newnumCooler,
            phoneNum: this.state.newphoneNum,
            pickUp: this.state.newpickUp
        }

        if (this.props.riderList.partyNM === riders.partyNM) {
            console.log(riders);
        } else {
            console.log(this.props.riderList)
            console.log(riders.partyNM)
            console.log("Didn't work")
        }
    }

    onDragEnd = (result) => {
        if (!result.destination) {
            return;
        }
        if (
            result.destination.droppableId === result.source.droppableId && result.destination.index === result.source.index
        ) {
            return;
        }

        if (result.type === 'vans') {
            this.props.reorderVans(result, this.props.vansList);
        }

    };

    renderVans() {
        //Testing to see what is in my props for the two 
        console.log(this.props.vansList);
        console.log(this.props.riderList);
        const vanslist = this.props.vansList;
        return (vanslist.map((van, index) => {
            return (
                <Buscard key={van.P_Key} vanList={van} index={index} />
            )
        }));
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <DragDropContext
                    onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}
                >
                    <DispatchHeader
                        createVan={this.handleVanCreation}
                        open={this.state.openModal}
                        close={this.toggleModalState}
                        onVanChange={this.handleNameVanChange}
                        onTotalChange={this.handleTotalSeatsChage}
                        vanName={this.state.nameVan}
                        totalSeats={this.state.seatsTotal}
                    />
                    <div style={buttonStyle}>
                        <Button
                            onClick={this.toggleModalState}
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className="w-half"
                        >
                            ADD Van
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classNames("flex flex-1 overflow-x-auto overflow-y-hidden")}>

                        <Droppable
                            droppableId={this.state.columns}
                            type="vans"
                            direction="horizontal"
                        >
                            {(provided) => (
                                <div ref={provided.innerRef} className="flex p-16 md:p-24">
                                    {this.renderVans()}
                                    {/*Whatever reason having them commented out loads them, however on initial they don't....*/}
                                    {provided.placeholder}
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Droppable>
                    </div>
                    <Paper>
                        <Table>
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell>Party Name</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Address</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Number in Party</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Number of Coolers</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Phone Number</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Pick Up</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell >Edit</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Add to Van</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            {/*this.renderRiders()*/}
                        </Table>
                    </Paper>
                </DragDropContext>
            </div >
        )
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getVansList: Actions.getVansList,
        getRiderList: Actions.getRiderList,
        reorderVans: Actions.reorderVans,
        addVan: Actions.addVan,
    }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        vansList: state.vansList,
        riderList: state.riderList,
        //serData: state.userData
    }
}


export default withReducer('adminApp', reducer)(withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminApp)));
```

Get Rider List Action

```
import { GET_RIDER_LIST, GET_VANS_LIST } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Actions from './index';

export function getRiderList() {

    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('https://8alpuah738.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/riderinfo/getriders/')
            .then(response =>
                dispatch(
                    getRiderListAsync(response.data))
            );

        axios.get('https://8alpuah738.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/vaninfo')
            .then(response =>
                dispatch(getVansListAsync(response.data))
            )

    }
}
function getRiderListAsync(riders) {
    //console.log(riders);
    return {
        type: GET_RIDER_LIST,
        payload: riders
    };
}

function getVansListAsync(vans) {
    //console.log(vans);
    return {
        type: GET_VANS_LIST,
        payload: vans
    };
}
```

Get Rider Reducer

```
import {
    GET_RIDER_LIST
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = null;

const riderReducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_RIDER_LIST:
            {
                return { ...action.payload }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default riderReducer;
```

Connect Reducer to store:

```
import * as reduxModule from 'redux';
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import createReducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

/*
Fix for Firefox redux dev tools extension
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-instrument/pull/19#issuecomment-400637274
 */
reduxModule.__DO_NOT_USE__ActionTypes.REPLACE = '@@redux/INIT';

const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
            // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
        }) : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

const store = createStore(createReducer(), + window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__&& window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), enhancer);

store.asyncReducers = {};

export const injectReducer = (key, reducer) => {
    if ( store.asyncReducers[key] )
    {
        return;
    }
    store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer;
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));
    return store;
};

export default store;
```

Comment: can you show how you are connect reducer to store?so that it will be easy to guess what is the issue.

Comment: @Neelam added the code above

Comment: if you put a console log in the `mapStateToProps` function are you seeing the right data change

Comment: @azium it shows as null there as well for adminApp.

Comment: are you not using `react-redux`'s Provider component and passing in the store? I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your `withReducer` HoC

Comment: In my App.js I do pass the store to Provider. I use with reducer to handle asynchronous data instead of just calling the reducer which is synchronous.

Comment: @azium see above